# Assertion failure in [UITableView configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am taking an assertion failure while try to use a custom cell from .xib in my Base ViewController.

I have also set up my cellIdentifier, what might be wrong?

Here is my sample code;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CartItemTableViewCell *cell = [cartView.cartTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:_cellIdentifier];


if (!cell) {
    cell = [[CartItemTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:_cellIdentifier];
}

OrderObject *tempOrderObject = [[OrderHelper returnCurrentCart] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell.itemNameLabel setText:tempOrderObject.itemName];
[cell.itemPriceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",tempOrderObject.itemPrice]];
[cell.itemDetailLabel setText:tempOrderObject.itemDetail];

cell.delegate = self;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

return cell;    
}
```

I am also registering as follows

```
_cellIdentifier = @"cartItemCell";
    [cartView.cartTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CartItemTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:_cellIdentifier];
```

Error;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7cbdd800; frame = (0 63; 320 280); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x84d478e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bfcb5f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 44}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `if (!cell) {` code working? what is the value of `cellIndentifier`?

Comment: What exactly is the assertion that is failing?

Comment: can you post more of the error?

Comment: Make sure `return cell; ` at the end of the method is not returning `nil`.

Comment: create a breakpoint at `cell.delegate = self;` and check if cell is nil.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to tell exactly what is the cause of the error from what you posted. But this is one of the most common causes, check if it applies to you :

If you are using a custom cell you have to register you custom nib file to the tableView. Like this:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CartItemTableViewCell"
                              bundle:nil];

[[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:_cellIdentifier];
```

Comment: @erdemgc Oh ok. can you post more of the error? I will keep updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try remove:

```
if (!cell) {
     cell = [[CartItemTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:_cellIdentifier];
}
```

I think it don't necessary.

Comment: That depends on his deployment target; it will not do any harm, but removing this code can fail at runtime on older iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

What das your Nib contain? Make sure that calling `[[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CartItemTableViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]` returns a valid `UITableViewCell`and also, in your XIB, set the reuse identifier on your cell using the attribute inspector.